`BGAppRefreshTask` Handler Not Being Called Despite Proper Setup in iOS App
I’m working on implementing a background task in my iOS app using BGAppRefreshTask. I’ve followed all the steps to set it up, but the background task did not work for the background and terminated application states. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Setup Details:

Signing & Capabilities Configuration: Enabled Background fetch and Background Processing options.

Info.plist Configuration:
I’ve added the BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers key with my background task identifier (e.g., "com.example.myapp.refresh").

Registering the Background Task:
In application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:), I call the registerBackgroundTask() method to register the task:
func registerBackgroundTask() {
    BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.myapp.refresh", using: nil) { task in
        guard let task = task as? BGAppRefreshTask else {
            return
        }
        Task {
            await self.scheduleNotificationIfNeeded()
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        }
        task.expirationHandler = {
            print("BGAppRefreshTask is expired")
        }
    }
}


Scheduling the Task: I’m scheduling the task like this:
let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.myapp.refresh")
request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60) // 15 minutes later for testing.

do {
    try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
} catch {
    print("Failed to submit BGAppRefreshTaskRequest: \(error)")
}


Testing Conditions: I've tested all these conditions with a physical device and not with a simulator. I learned that it's not working in Simulator. Here is the conditions that I gave a try:



I've tried both the app is in background & terminated states and wait for the
task to trigger, There is no triggered notification.
I've verified that:

The task identifier in the code matches the one in Info.plist.
The registerBackgroundTask function is being called in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).
The task is scheduled with an earliestBeginDate of 61 seconds for testing.




Debugging Attempts:


Added print statements to see if the handler is called (it's not) in the background app state.
Used Xcode’s Simulate Background Fetch debug option to trigger the background task, but still no luck.
Verified that the device is not in Low Power Mode and Background app refresh toggle is ON in the app settings.

Question:
What could be causing the BGAppRefreshTask does not work despite having everything seemingly set up correctly? Is there anything else I should be checking or any potential issues with iOS’s background task handling that could be causing this?
Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
Result:
After thorough research, I discovered that there is no guaranteed solution for ensuring the execution of background tasks in iOS. The iOS system uses an internal prioritization mechanism that depends heavily on the current device state and user behavior. Consequently, it is not advisable to rely on background tasks for handling critical business cases, as iOS makes its own decision on whether to execute the task based on several factors.
Some key factors influencing iOS's decision-making process include:
1) User Activity: If the user is not a frequent user of the app, iOS may deprioritize or even skip the scheduled background task execution.
2) Manual App Termination: If the user forcefully kills the app, any scheduled background tasks will not be executed.
3) Low Power Mode: When Low Power Mode is enabled, iOS may delay or prevent background task execution to conserve battery life.
4) Battery Level: If the device's battery is low, iOS may choose to delay or skip the task in order to optimize power consumption.
These factors, among others, illustrate the inherent uncertainty in relying on background tasks for time-sensitive operations in iOS.

In Terminated State, it won't trigger. You won't see it triggered with Xcode attached. I'd suggest you to post a Local Notification to replace your print when testing.

Nice idea! It might lead me about what's happening. Let me to give a try. Thanks!

That's how I debugged it, that's why I know the trick. It's easier than using log files and read them afterward...

Unfortunately did not work :/ I've replaced all prints with scheduling a local notification and not received any notification. It shows that all setup is correct. But somehow, it's not working.
Also, I saw in a resource and it states that iOS executes the background tasks within the task queue in every 15 minutes. Could it be possible?  But still, it should have worked. I also tried to wait even 20 minutes.

Physical device, no Xcode attached, put the app in background, but do not kill it. Did you try with these conditions? And It's the OS that decide when to do the background task, you decide on a prefered time, but it's the OS that decides.

Yes, I've tried with these conditions exactly.

Put it, and leave it for a few hours. Usually at night it's better (since the iPhone detect it's not used).

Note that "simulate background fetch" is for the old background refresh capability. There is a different method for triggering BGAppRefresh tasks

Nice info! Thank you! will give a try this as well  @Paulw11

I've tested in the midnight and no result. Not Xcode attached, the app was in background. @Larme

That is really amazing way to test it! @Paulw11. I've tested using debugger command and it works for both background and terminated states. Seems the command is overriding earliestBeginDate property as now and it's working. It's interesting that it's not working with the tasks which are set to the future.

Is the app in background allowed in Settings.app ? Did you check the sample app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing-and-maintaining-your-app-using-background-tasks ? Does it work? You could quickly add the Notification trick to it. Maybe there is a missing point in your app.

I've tried this sample project built by Apple and it's working unstable like in my project. It's executing task rarely. My device was not in the low power mode for all my attempts and background app refresh toggle was ON. I've also tried to change task execution time and scheduled it 30 mins later from now because it might be requiring more flexible time, it did not work. But it's all the time working if I run the debugger command as it's firing the task immediately ‍♂️
